# Custom pager for View

Tags: views, paging

The client I'm building a site for has a collection of content that they want paged by its ReleaseYear Field. The pager they want should look like:

```
[ < | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | > ]
```

How I build a pager like that?

Answer (score 1):

As a clue,  you should alter the `theme_pager_link` function. copy this function in the `template.php`, if the years are started from 2001, you need to alter the pager so that every link of the pager be summed with 2000, it is the function

```
function THEME_pager_link($variables) {
  $text = $variables['text'];
  $page_new = $variables['page_new'];
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];

  $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
  if ($new_page = implode(',', pager_load_array($page_new[$element], $element, explode(',', $page)))) {
    $parameters['page'] = $new_page;
  }

  $query = array();
  if (count($parameters)) {
    $query = drupal_get_query_parameters($parameters, array());
  }
  if ($query_pager = pager_get_query_parameters()) {
    $query = array_merge($query, $query_pager);
  }

  // Set each pager link title
  if (!isset($attributes['title'])) {
    static $titles = NULL;
    if (!isset($titles)) {
      $titles = array(
        t('« first') => t('Go to first page'),
        t('‹ previous') => t('Go to previous page'),
        t('next ›') => t('Go to next page'),
        t('last »') => t('Go to last page'),
      );
    }
    if (isset($titles[$text])) {
      $attributes['title'] = $titles[$text];
    }
    elseif (is_numeric($text)) {
      $text = $text + 2000;  ------>>>>> in this line every number is added with 2000
      $attributes['title'] = t('Go to page @number', array('@number' => $text));
    }
  }

  // @todo l() cannot be used here, since it adds an 'active' class based on the
  //   path only (which is always the current path for pager links). Apparently,
  //   none of the pager links is active at any time - but it should still be
  //   possible to use l() here.
  // @see http://drupal.org/node/1410574
  $attributes['href'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => $query));
  return '<a' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . check_plain($text) . '</a>';
}
```

the indicated line with  `------>>>>>` add every number with 2000, the only shortage of this solution is that the current number won't be summed with 2000. A few modification to this code will solve this problem as well. you can also add any css class to `$attributes` variable.

Comment: Can I build something like this such that it only appears on a particular page, or am I overriding the general function?

Comment: general function

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this the following way :

- ReleaseYear would be a taxonomy.
- Then you'd have it defined in your view an exposed filter.
- And you'd theme your filter to be displayed as links.

Does that make sense to you ?